# Autocomplete search in dropdown not working (Angular 12)

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete, dropdown, angular12

I have tried few ways to solve this autocomplete search inside dropdown in Angular material but nothing seems to work.

**HTML:**

```
    <form [formGroup]="form" autocomplete="off">
----other form fields---
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label class="label-padding">Menu Icon</mat-label>
               <input type="text" placeholder="Search Icon" formControlName="icons" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
                   <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
                       <mat-option value="">Search icon</mat-option>
                       <mat-option value="{{each.value}}" *ngFor="let each of filteredOptions"(click)="onSelFunc(each.value)">
                        <mat-icon>{{each.value}}</mat-icon> {{each.text}}
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
     </form>
```

**COMPONENT:**

```
filteredOptions: any
ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      //others,
      icons: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    })
    this.menuIconDropdown = this.iconListModel.iconList;
    this.filteredOptions = this.icons.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
      console.log(this.filteredOptions );
  }
private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    console.log(value);
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.menuIconDropdown.filter((option: any) => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
  onSelFunc(option: any) {
    console.log(option);
  }
```

The dropdown list is showing properly, but the search & autocomplete are not working at all.

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I have made here?

Answer (score 0):

return type of filter function is `string[]` and  your `menuIconDropdown` is a key value list so your filter function should be like this:

```
private _filter(value: string): any[] {
    console.log(value);
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.menuIconDropdown.filter((option: any) => option.text.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
```

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: convert your `menuIconDropdown`  to `string[ ]` and try again.